# Order by specific values from column

Tags: mysql

I have table for billings. Now, I want to retrieve all the data but there is discounts so, the discounts has two type, fixed amount and a percentage, percentage is in decimal forms for example: -0.10 for 10%, the discounts must be the last to get and it is ordered by asc. Sorry for my bad english. Here's my table:

```
id       |    bill_item_id       |      bill_item_amount
1        |    1                  |      1000
2        |    3                  |      -0.12
3        |    2                  |      -100
4        |    4                  |      -0.15
```

bill_item_id = 2 represents that the discount is fixed, if it is in percentage the bill_item_id is any number.

Expected output must be:

```
id       |      bill_item_amount
1        |      1000
3        |      -100
4        |      -0.15
2        |      -0.12
```

My Query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM billing_details order by bill_item_amount < 0 and bill_item_amount > -1 asc
```

My query only checks for percentage discounts but I want to check the fixed discounts also. The order would be normal item, fixed discount, percentage discount ascending.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
  id, bill_item_amount
from
  billing_details
order by
  bill_item_amount desc;
```

Comment: This couldn't order fixed amount first then percentage.

Comment: Oops, I miss read the question. The other answer will do. But it's a terrible idea to keep two different type of data in one column without proper categorization. Your data should be normalized. Who knows -0.15 is not an actually amount?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, You need this:

```
SELECT *       
FROM billing_details 
ORDER BY  
CASE    WHEN  bill_item_amount >= 0 bill_item_amount END DESC,
CASE    WHEN  bill_item_amount < 0 THEN bill_item_amount END ASC
```